# Pathways: Manipulate list of events in parent-child 'nodes' in R

Tags: r, igraph, data-manipulation

I am interested in visualizing pathways patients have based on a pre-specified list of events (e.g. diagnosis, surgery, treatment1, treatment2, death).

A test data set might look like this:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
    Event = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    5L, 1L), .Label = c("death", "diagnosis", "surgery", "treatment1", 
    "treatment2"), class = "factor"), date = structure(c(14610, 
    14619, 16667, 14975, 14976, 14977, 15074, 15084, 15006, 15050, 
    15051, 15053), class = "Date")), .Names = c("ID", "Event", 
"date"), row.names = c(NA, 12L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   ID      Event       date
1   a  diagnosis 2010-01-01
2   a    surgery 2010-01-10
3   a      death 2015-08-20
4   b  diagnosis 2011-01-01
5   b    surgery 2011-01-02
6   b treatment1 2011-01-03
7   b treatment2 2011-04-10
8   b      death 2011-04-20
9   c  diagnosis 2011-02-01
10  c    surgery 2011-03-17
11  c treatment2 2011-03-18
12  c      death 2011-03-20
```

The data have been ordered by ID and date.

What I am after is the following:

```
> result
  ID     parent      child datediff
1  a  diagnosis    surgery        9
2  a    surgery      death     1950
3  b  diagnosis    surgery        1
4  b    surgery treatment1        1
5  b treatment1 treatment2       90
6  b treatment2      death       10
7  c  diagnosis    surgery       45
8  c    surgery treatment2        1
9  c treatment2      death        2
```

(Note that the numbers in the datediff column are not actual)
i.e. a series of parent-child nodes with the difference in dates between them.

This will allow me to plot the nodes, and do some further descriptive analysis on time between events.

I found a package to plot nodes (see below)... Is there a way/package that allows the arrow width to reflect the number of parent-child combinations?

```
 require(igraph) # possible package to use
 parents<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","C","C","F","F","H","I")
 children<-c("I","I","I","I","B","A","D","H","G","H","I","J")
 begats<-data.frame(parents=parents,children=children)
 graph_begats<-graph.data.frame(begats)
 tkplot(graph_begats)
```

Answer (score 2):

Collapse your data up to give each parent-child combo and a count of how many times they occurred, e.g.:

```
# put the previous event against the current event, and drop the rows before the first event:
df$Event <- as.character(df$Event)
df$PreEvent <- with(df, ave(Event,ID,FUN=function(x) c(NA,head(x,-1)) ) )
result <- df[!is.na(df$PreEvent),c("ID","PreEvent","Event")]

# aggregate the combos by how often they occur:
result <- aggregate(list(count=rownames(result)),result[c("PreEvent","Event")],FUN=length)
#    PreEvent      Event count
#1    surgery      death     1
#2 treatment2      death     2
#3  diagnosis    surgery     3
#4    surgery treatment1     1
#5    surgery treatment2     1
#6 treatment1 treatment2     1

# plot in igraph, adjusting the edge.width to account for how many cases of each
# parent-child combo exist:
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(result)
plot(g,edge.width=result$count)
```

[image]