# iGraph Weighted Network Plot

Tags: r, igraph, sqldf

I haven't found a question that covers my situation exactly.  I have a list of web traffic nodes that I want to plot and keep the plot readable.  Of the thousands of transactions in a day there are only about 152 different page couplets.  I want to adjust the weight of the lines to give an idea of how often the connection happens.  At present I have the data in two forms.  The first is a simple list of the couplets i.e.

```
Node1     Node2
Home      Info
Info      Specials
Home      Info
Info      About
About     Specials
```

Or I can give an ordered list that has a count of each couplet i.e.

```
Node1     Node2    Cnt
Home      Info     2
Info      Specials 1
Info      About    1
About     Specials 1
```

Ideally I would like to weight the graph by 'Cnt'  Do I need to insert an index of some sort and split the columns, or is there a way to access 'Cnt' with iGraph directly?

I am using R, with SQLDF & iGraph to do this work.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365575/pathways-manipulate-list-of-events-in-parent-child-nodes-in-r/32365720 ?

Comment: I couldn't find that yesterday.  Thanks that is just what I needed.